# Decision theory - reject option

Tags: decision-theory

In decision theory, we define a reject option ($\theta$) so that when making decision is difficult, the case will be ignored.

Suppose $1/k \leq \theta \leq1$:

- If $\theta=1/k$ no cases will be rejected

  and
- If $\theta=1$ all cases will be rejected.

Why this happes and how can I prove it for $\theta=1$ and $1/k$?

Section 1.5.3, chapter 1 of [Pattern recognition by Bishop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387310738): (reject option)

> We have seen that classification errors arise from the regions of input space
> where the largest of the posterior probabilities p(Ck|x) is significantly less than unity,
> or equivalently where the joint distributions p(x, Ck) have comparable values. These
> are the regions where we are relatively uncertain about class membership. In some
> applications, it will be appropriate to avoid making decisions on the difficult cases
> in anticipation of a lower error rate on those examples for which a classification decision
> is made. This is known as the reject option. For example, in our hypothetical
> medical illustration, it may be appropriate to use an automatic system to classify
> those X-ray images for which there is little doubt as to the correct class, while leaving
> a human expert to classify the more ambiguous cases. We can achieve this by
> introducing a threshold θ and rejecting those inputs x for which the largest of the
> posterior probabilities p(Ck|x) is less than or equal to θ. This is illustrated for the
> case of two classes, and a single continuous input variable x, in Figure 1.26. **Note
> that setting θ = 1 will ensure that all examples are rejected, whereas if there are K
> classes then setting θ < 1/K will ensure that no examples are rejected. Thus the
> fraction of examples that get rejected is controlled by the value of θ.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An input $x$ is rejected if the largest posterior probability $\max_{i=1,\ldots,k}{\rm P}(\mbox{belongs to class } i|x)\leq\theta$.

There are $k$ classes and the probabilities must sum to 1: $$\sum_{i=1}^k{\rm P}(\mbox{belongs to class } i|x)=1.$$
A consequence of this is that $$\max_{i=1,\ldots,k}{\rm P}(\mbox{belongs to class } i|x)\geq 1/k$$
as the sum of probabilities otherwise necessarily must be less than $1$. This means that if $\theta=1/k$ the input is never rejected, since there is at least one posterior probability that is larger than $\theta$.

Similarly, we have that
$$\max_{i=1,\ldots,k}{\rm P}(\mbox{belongs to class } i|x)\leq 1$$
with equality only if there are $x$ that only can belong to one class. If no such $x$ can exist,
$$\max_{i=1,\ldots,k}{\rm P}(\mbox{belongs to class } i|x)< 1$$
which means that if $\theta=1$ all inputs are rejected, since the maximum posterior probability always is less than $1$.